# filling everything while rotating

Tags: html, css

When I rotate my div by 177deg it rotates fine but everyting is not filled https://prnt.sc/sklcga just like this image is it possible to fill it all?

```html
 <div class="head">
 </div>
```

```css
.head{
  width:100%;
  height:450px;
  background:#fff;
  transform: rotate(177deg);
}
```

Comment: Make the div wider?

Comment: @disinfor it it's solution to my problem sure, but when i set width more than 100% overflox-x appears if I hide overflow project screws up

Comment: How about wrapping the head element in another element and setting the parent to overflow hidden? Pretty simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more suitable for skew:

```css
.head{
  height:450px;
  background:#fff;
  transform: skewY(177deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}

body {
  background:red;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
 </div>
```